# I am not able to pass a global variable between 2 files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have experience only in C# .net and no experience in Python 3.5.

I am stuck at passing a global variable value between 2 .py files. I read and tried a lot of examples and tutorials from the net and pages from this forum, but it is not working.

I split my Python project into many py files. In my `mainfile.py` file, I read a txt, take a line from file (as a url), and assign the url to a variable.

```
the_url_var=line
```

I call / import the second `openbrowser.py` file, where I must open the browser and to go to that url. (I used also `global the_url_var`). I got a "Variable not declared" error. I had no problem read the file, opening the browser and so on. The problem is only with the global variable passing.
I tried even to use and import an 3rd file `config.py` with global the_url_var .

Any tips or maybe a simple and explicit tutorial?

Just to mention: I do not declare and use a function inside my program.

Comment: The only tip is *use a function* and pass the variables explicitly. There is no good reason to do anything else.

Comment: Just to clarify: you do not declare functions, do you?

Comment: No i do not deckare functions. It is so simple so i considered that i do not need functions...

Comment: @DanielRoseman ...thank you , but where to use the function..

Comment: @DanielRoseman ...thank you , but where to use the function?..I have let say 2 files: mainfile.py and openbrowser.py     I must to declare the function () inside the mainfile.py and after that to use in openbrowser.py? And also inside the function() i must to declare global the_url_var.   That way  the_url_var will carry and pass a certain value from mainfile.py to openbrowser.py  to use there?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

My files look like:

## variabileglobale.py

global vargl

## mainfile.py

import variabileglobale

variabileglobale.vargl=3

import doit

## doit.py

import variabileglobale

print(variabileglobale.vargl)

=================================

The result is printing 3 and it is working

For the @khelwood. I saw the work you did editing my previus post . Please understand me. I do not speak english. I learn some english by my self and sometimes i translate with google translate. So sorry for my poor english. I always do my best to corect my posts.